How to implement „generator history“ GAN in Keras/Tensorflow
Generative Adversial Networks (GANs) are a very interesting type of generative models, however hard to train. One method to improve the stability is provided by this paper:    In section 2.3 they argue that

A problem of adversial training is that the discriminator network only focuses on the latest refined images.

and

[…] we introduce a method to improve the stability by updating the discriminator using a history of refined images, rather than only the ones in the current mini-batch.

This just means that we have to keep a history of generated images from the generator (e.g. the last 50 images) and show them to the discriminator randomly.
This approach is also used in the CycleGAN.
My question is
How can I implement this approach of updating the discriminator with a history of images by overwriting the Keras model class? In fact, I would like to extend the keras CycleGAN implementation (found here ) by this approach.
I found an implementation using the
train_on_batch

in this tutorial. However, I can not succeed to do the same thing by using the
model.train

method as described in the Keras tutorial.
